# Linguistics resources for beginners

Tags: syntax, phonology, morphology, reference-request, resource-request

I'm currently reading Jackendoff's [Foundations of language](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199264376) and I've realised that my knowledge of syntax, morphology and phonology isn't as strong as I'd like it to be. I'm coming from a psych background, and I'm quite comfortable reading psycholinguistics texts. However, (and this is a point that Jackendoff makes) I've realised that the psycholinguistics I've come into contact with thus far seems to downplay the complexity of language. As someone who would like to pursue a career in the cognitive sciences and who has an interest in language, I'd like to address this gap in my knowledge.

So my question for you is this: What are some good resources for those of us who are curious about language, and can comfortably tackle some of the more basic literature, but who don't have the same level of knowledge that a linguistics graduate would have?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many linguistics graduates have rather limited visions of many areas in linguistics, so you're definitely not alone. And one needn't follow Jackendoff's prescriptions uncritically, either. The Crystal Encyclopedias are basic, so they may be too simple. But they're pretty inclusive and have good bibliographies.